# This SDK is not supported by the compiler. Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK

Tags: ios, xcode13, swift5

I have created one iOS framework. The framework was **build by XCode version 12.5.1**.
When I am using this framework with **XCode 13.0**, I am getting below error.

```
This SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.4.2 
(swiftlang-1205.0.28.2 clang-1205.0.19.57)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5
 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.1 clang-1300.0.29.1)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.
```

Does anyone also faced this issue ?  Please reply.

Comment: What you did to solve this?